# How can I craft weapons and masks?

Tags: payday-2

There seems to be a crafting system in the game, but I can't find it. Where is it and how does it work?

[image: Improved Crafting - Your cost of weapon crafting is reduced.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Improved Crafting perk reduces the cost of adding mods to your weapons and, when aced, the cost of customizing your mask.

You don't actually craft weapons in Payday 2.

Mods available for purchase can be viewed by double-clicking the weapon you want to mod within your inventory.

Comment: Your nickname fits the answer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I try my best :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no crafting system, however you can apply modifications to your weapons. You can read more about the crafting systems in this [payday 2 weapons guide](http://www.altergamer.com/payday-2-general-weapons-guide/)